# Java Inheritance doubt in parameterised collection

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

It's obvious that a parent class's object can hold a reference to a child, but does this not hold true in case of parameterised collection ??

eg:

```
Car class is parent of Sedan
```

So

```
public void doSomething(Car c){
    ...
}

public void caller(){
    Sedan s = new Sedan();
    doSomething(s);
}
```

is obviously valid

But

```
public void doSomething(Collection<Car> c){
    ...
}

public void caller(){
    Collection<Sedan> s = new ArrayList<Sedan>();
    doSomething(s);
}
```

Fails to compile

Can someone please point out why? and also, how to implement such a scenario where a function needs to iterate through a Collection of parent objects, modifying only the fields present in parent class, using parent class methods, but the calling methods (say 3 different methods) pass the collection of three different subtypes..

Ofcourse it compiles fine if I do as below:

```
public void doSomething(Collection<Car> c){
    ...
}

public void caller(){
    Collection s = new ArrayList<Sedan>();
    doSomething(s);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
public void doSomething(Collection<? extends Car> c){}
```

or (as suggested)

```
public <T extends Car> void doSomething(Collection<T> c){}
```

This would mean that the `Collection` is of any subclass of `Car` (or `Car` itself), rather than "It's a collection of `Car` instances only"

This is because collections are *invariant*, unlike arrays, which are *covariant*. To quote [Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/):

> Covariant [..] means that if `Sub` is a subtype of `Super`, then the array type `Sub[]` is a subtype of `Super[]`. Generics, by contrast, are *invariant*: for any two distinct types `Type1` and `Type2`, `List<Type1>` is neigther a subtype nor a supertype of `List<Type2>`.

Comment: If you know that the collection is homogeneous, the better way to write the method signature is <code>public <T extends Car> void doSomething(Collection<T> c)</code>

Answer (score 2):

`doSomething` needs to be declared `doSomething(Collection<? extends Car> c)`. Declared that way, you will not be able to add any elements to the collection, because you do not know what specific subclass of `Car` that collection is supposed to contain.

The general issue here is that a `Collection<Sedan>` simply cannot be considered a subclass of `Collection<Car>` because you can't do everything on a `Collection<Sedan>` that you can on a `Collection<Car>`. For instance, you can `add` a `SportsCar` to a `Collection<Car>` because a `SportsCar` is a `Car`. You can't add a `SportsCar` to a `Collection<Sedan>` because a `SportsCar` is not a `Sedan`.